# cocapods duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I've just updated my App to iOS9 and Xcode 7 and after that I always get the message:

1332 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

I'm using cocoapods for dependencies resolution, and if I edit Pods.xcconfig I get rid of the message but I get exceptions in my application.

I also modified Podfile and included directive use_frameworks! but I still have problems with the linker.

Updating cocoapods to last version 0.39.4 didn't help either.

Thanks in advance for your help